# list.files() on a specific sub-directory in a folder tree

Tags: r

I have a huge folder structure like :

```
main
  |____ A1
  |     |__proj_doc
  |            |__ some txt files
  |____ B2
  |     |__proj_doc
  |            |__ some txt files
  |____ C3
        |__proj doc
               |__ tmp
               |    |__ some txt files
               | 
               |__ some txt files
```

and would like to list all the `txt` files from all `proj_doc` and `proj doc` folders.

```
mylist <-list.files(path = "/main", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.txt$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)
```

will list all the files but from the root `main` folder, including all the sub folders, which cause a lot of unnecessary data. How could I correct the path to just look into correct sub-directories ?

Comment: Do two searches.  The first to identify all the `proj doc` folders, the second to loop through the list of `proj doc` folders to identify the contents of each.  `list.files(include.dirs=TRUE)` will probably be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s one way:

```
dirs = list.dirs('main')
proj_doc_dirs = grep('/proj./proj[ _]doc', dirs, value = TRUE)
txt_files = dir(proj_doc_dirs, pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have changed the folder structure. Basically if I have some sub folder inside the `proj_doc` in your method those will be scanned as well and all the `txt` files from those will be listed. In my example I do not want the files from `tmp` directory ! but just the `proj_doc` or `proj doc`